# Magento 2 theme not loading my css files

Tags: magento2, css, parent-child-theme

I am new to Magento theme development. I have gone through the frontend development guide and set up my child theme of the Magento Blank theme. I have done all that the guide says and added my css file but it is not showing on the frontend. Below is my setup. Any help would be great!

design/frontend/DouglasMedia/henryhiggs

Inside the folder henryhiggs it is:

```
|-etc
|  |-view.xml
|
|- Magnto_theme
|  |-layout
|      |-default_head_blocks.xml
|      |-default.xml
|
|-media
|   |-preview.jpg
|
|-web
|   |-css
|      |-custom.css
|   |-fonts
|   |-images
|   |-js
|
|-registration.php
|-theme.xml
```

Here is the code for default default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

    <css src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" src_type="url"/>

    <css src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" src_type="url"/>
    <css src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900" src_type="url"/>
    <css src="css/custom.css" />

    <script src="jquery.js" />
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
</head>
```

Here is the code for the theme.xml file

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
 <title>Henry Higgs Theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
 <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
 <media>
     <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
 </media>
 </theme>
```

Let me know if I need to give any more code for any of the other files.

I have tried to run the following commands and then cleared the cache and so joy.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Only other thing it might be is that there is no files under design/frontend/Magento/blank. I looked at another forum and they said it was ok as it is stored elsewhere. It seems to be the case as the "blank" theme is showing when I have my custom theme activated. Only cannot see any custom css I add.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling mistake For theme and magento. Should be **Magento_Theme**, not **Magnto_theme**

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala it is correct answer.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Thanks for this. I changed it and seems to work but only on all the other pages such as category and product pages. On the home page the css is not loading and to make it even stranger it shows the default Magento logo and not the site logo like all the other pages, any ideas?

Comment: Try to run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` one more time to see if your issues resolved.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but no luck. :(

Comment: How about clear cache by `bin/magento cache:flush`? If still not working,  check the CSS files itself. I think there are some override on styles. And, try to reupload your logo.

Comment: thank you @QaisarSatti I have read only answer not read what is the question sorry its my mistake

Comment: @QaisarSatti thanks very much! It now shows. :D

What is the difference between clearing the cache in dashboard and using ssh to flush? seems as though when done through dash it didnt do it.

Comment: read this https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/issues/588